# Why is data-contextual-id showing for guests in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

Im new to Drupal so forgive me if this is a really basic, stupid question but here goes...

From what I understand the data-contextual-id is used so that Drupal knows what blocks / elements are editable using quick edit when an administrator is logged in(?), however, when I'm logged out of the website and view the website as a regular visitor (incognito mode) I'm still seeing the data-contextual-id which as an exaple from one part looks like:

```
data-contextual-id="block:block=jethro_footer:langcode=en|menu:menu=footer:langcode=en"
```

I've looked though countless websites built on Drupal 7 and havent found this anywhere, so how do I stop it showing when not logged in, so my source code is cleaner?

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: i've got exactly the same problem... don't know why they are still there if not logged in...

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have filed a issue on drupal core, if you could report your problem also there we might get the attention of the module maintainers. https://www.drupal.org/node/2650246#comment-10748430

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question and led to some debates... but short answer now is: that's fixed as of early March/2016. It may take a while to show up in the next release, but the issue is gone.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2528498

But to summarize the "why" - it had to do with the cache system. Drupal stores each node in a cache now; to serve different cached versions of the page for anons and auth users would have required something like 6 versions in  6 different cache locations (don't ask my why). However, a recent change now means that it's much simpler to store different anon and auth versions, as I believe there is a new mechanism that allows this to be done with 2 versions in 2 cache locations.

The "how" of getting rid of the clutter is to wait for a few (weeks?) for the relevant drupal version, or in the meantime uninstall the Quick Edit module.

edit: not just nodes but all pages are cached